# array pointer type for function return

Tags: arrays, c, types

I started using array pointers a lot recently because it simplify a lot the allocation/deallocation, but the type always throw an error by the compiler when its the return type of a function.
this is accepted :

```
int (*arr_ptr)[SIZE] = NULL;
```

but this is not:

```
int (*)[] foo(void) {
    return NULL;
}
```

the compiler throw this error:

```
src/main.c:51:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’ token
   51 | int (*)[] foo(void) {
      |       ^
```

For the moment I just typedef the type and it  work:

```
typedef int(*tdarr_ptr_int)[];
tdarr_ptr_int foo(void) {
    return NULL;
}
```

But this not a suitable longterm solution for me, how can I specify this return type without having to typedef it?

Comment: You can't return an array in C. You can return a pointer or a struct, though, or just pass an array (maybe a VLA) as a function parameter.

Comment: The typedef is a good solution, it's not clear why you would consider it less suitable than the alternative

Comment: @Bob__ I am returning a pointer, a pointer to an array.

Comment: @M.M because I can just type `int(*arr)[SIZE] = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE*SIZE);` and  it give me a 2 dimension array of SIZE * SIZE, the same way you define one with just `int arr[SIZE][SIZE];`, but now its malloced, and can return it with a function, and free it with just a free, and don't have to make an array of array which are a pain to free in higher dimension.

Comment: @Bamontan what does that have to do with the typedef? BTW it would be better style to typedef the array type, not the pointer to array

Comment: @M.M ho I think I misread your question, I'm sorry. The alternative is good but I don't find it really clear to read.

Comment: @M.M Also, what do you mean by: "typedef the array type, not the pointer to array" ?

Comment: `typedef int arr_t[SIZE];`

Comment: @M.M Hoooo I see, yes I would do that, so If I understand correctly I would type something like : `arr_t* foo(void);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C uses infix notation , as we saw from your first example:

```
int (*arr_ptr)[SIZE] = NULL;
```

is correct whereas

```
int (*)[SIZE] arr_ptr = NULL;
```

is not.  You can fix the function version by applying the same principle:

```
int (*foo(void))[] {
```

NB. People sometimes criticize the infix, saying that postfix is easier, but hopefully it is clear from this example that the only difference is the placement of the identifier , and in fact having the identifier in the infix position helps you see where the middle is :)

Comment: thanks you ! the compiler does not throw errors anymore, its the only solution I haven't tried. But this is not really elegant... I think I will stick with the typedef, I found it more readable.